# String with space as one single Expect script argument

Tags: shell, parameter-passing, expect

I'm using expect to simulate sftp interactive prompt (`download_from_sftp.exp`):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set username [lindex $argv 0];
set server [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2];
set source [lindex $argv 3];
set target [lindex $argv 4];
set timeout 2400;

spawn sftp "$username@$server"
expect "password:"
send "$password\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get ${source} ${target}\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
interact
```

in which `$targe` is the output directory that contains space :(

How can I pass the argument so that it got treated as one argument? Currenly I'm using something like:

```
cmd="${git_directory}/sh/download_from_sftp.exp $sftp_username 
$sftp_server $sftp_password ${src_xml} ${target_xml}"
$cmd # run
```

in which the last argument will be expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell, you cannot "serialize" a command with arguments into a single string and get the command deserialized with some spaces as regular spaces and some as "special" spaces.

You need to use a shell array (bash, ksh, zsh all have arrays)

```
cmd=( 
    "$git_directory/sh/download_from_sftp.exp"
    "$sftp_username"
    "$sftp_server"
    "$sftp_password"
    "$src_xml"
    "$target_xml"
)
"${cmd[@]}" # run
```

All those quotes are required.

This is the only way to reliably keep the arguments containing whitespace as single entities.

In expect, you'll have to probably quote the arguments (for sftp's sake)

```
send "get $source \"$target"\r"
```

Normally, you send with `\r` not `\n` -- `\r` is a carriage return, or "hitting enter"

Comment: Nice solution & explanation. It worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the arguement with quotes:

```
cmd="${git_directory}/sh/download_from_sftp.exp $sftp_username $sftp_server$sftp_password \"${src_xml}\" \"${target_xml}\""
$cmd # run
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Threw me an "Unterminated quoted argument" - meaning that it still split on the whitespace.